# overwrite words in text file with python

Tags: python, replace, overwrite

I created a text file that contains in the first line a counter of created users and the rest of the lines the text contains user name, password..
for example:

```
2
username Name Last_name Password
username1 Name Last_name1 Password1
```

I'm using the following commands:

```
def SaveDatA(self):
    #if self.CheckValid() == False:
        #return
    with open("data.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(self.userEntry.get() + " " + self.NameEntry.get() + " " + self.LastEntry.get()+ " " + self.PasswordEntry.get() + "\n")
        self.counter += 1
```

I want to update the counter to the first line

Comment: I'll suggest you to simply remove the first line of total number cuz it's redundant.

Comment: You probably should create a temporary file with your desired content, and then os.rename() it to the original filename.  This is atomic, even on NFS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
f1_lines = open('data.txt', 'r').readlines()

with open('data.txt','w') as f:
         f.write(self.userEntry.get() + " " + self.NameEntry.get() + " " + self.LastEntry.get()+ " " + self.PasswordEntry.get() + "\n")
         self.counter += 1
         f1_lines[0]=str(self.counter)+'\n'
         f.write(''.join(f1_lines))
```

With `readlines()` you create a list contain all of lines in the file so you change the first index of that list with `f1_lines[0]=str(self.counter)+'\n'` then rewrite it in to the file !

Comment: I tried it- didn't work. I just want to edit the first line to the self.counter variable

Comment: I'm new to the programming world (include python). ill be thanksfull if u explain the changes.

Comment: i edit the answer ! try it ! i will add an explain about in answer !

Comment: didn't work but you helped me and now it's works but maybe there is a better way..i'll put it in the next answer to show what i did..

Comment: @Gabriel if it works you can tell this to community with vote and accepting the answer !

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials this code work's:

```
with open("data.txt","a") as f:
    f.write(self.userEntry.get() + " " + self.NameEntry.get() + " " + self.LastEntry.get()+ " " + self.PasswordEntry.get() + "\n")
    self.counter += 1

fileCopy = open('data.txt', 'r').readlines()
fileCopy[0] = fileCopy[0][1:]

with open("data.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(str(self.counter)+" ")
    f.write("".join(fileCopy))
```

but maybe there is another better way ?